# RegEx: Grabbing values with or without quotation marks

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

**My Issue:** 
I am trying to grab Facebook meta value from different sites, but some website(usatoday.com) are not having appropriate HTML code. As you can see the data sample 1 & 2, so my question is how can I modify my regex expression code to **get the value of the property and content**.

 
**What I've done:** 
With below if statement, I am kind of resolving the quotation mark issue (not dynamic enough), but I guess there must be a better way (I am really suck in regex)

Secondly, the regex I had not able to catch the content value(the url) in Data Sample 2 for usatoday.com, I guess the "" in the url mess up my regex.

Really need some help here, big thanks!

```php
if( 

preg_match( '/<meta(.*?)property="og:title"(.*?)content="(.+?)"(.*?)(\/)?>/', $raw_html, $matching )
// for normal sites

or

preg_match( '/<meta(.*?)property=og:title(.*?)content="(.+?)"(.*?)(\/)?>/', $raw_html, $matching )
// property no quote at all

or

preg_match( '/<meta(.*?)property=og:title(.*?)content=(.+?)(.*?)(\/)?>/', $raw_html, $matching ) 
// no quote at all

)
```

Data Sample 1 - no quotation mark on meta text attribute

```
# usatoday.com
<meta property=og:title content="Lakers trading Russell Westbrook in massive three-team deal with Jazz and Timberwolves"/>

# normal sites
<meta property="og:title" content="Lakers trading Russell Westbrook in massive three-team deal with Jazz and Timberwolves"/>
```

Data Sample 2 - no quotation mark on meta URL attribute

```
# usatoday.com
<meta property=og:url content=https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/2023/02/08/lakers-jazz-timberwolves-trade-russell-westbrook-mike-conley-dangelo-russell/11214855002/ />

# normal sites
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/2023/02/08/lakers-jazz-timberwolves-trade-russell-westbrook-mike-conley-dangelo-russell/11214855002/" />
```

Comment: `<meta(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\scontent\s*=\s*(?|(['"])\s*((?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?)\s*\1|()\s*((?:(?!["'\s>]|/>)[\S\s])*)))?(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sproperty\s*=\s*(?|(['"])\s*((?:(?!\3)[\S\s])*?)\s*\3|()\s*((?:(?!["'\s>]|/>)[\S\s])*)))?\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>(?(2)|(?(4)|(*SKIP)(*FAIL)))`  https://regex101.com/r/VdXeJJ/1  content is in group 2, property is in group 4. Both are optional but one must be there, enforced by the conditional at the end. You can make them both required and do away with the conditional. You can require specific property values, etc...

Comment: In addition, these attributes are matched out of order. Meaning they can appear anywhere within the meta tag. If you need it tweaked let me know.

Comment: Btw attribute 'values' do not have to be quoted. But they must adhere to the parsing rules for attribute values.

Comment: @sln Thank you very much! Based on your input, I modify my regex, and it works!!!!